# Attach data to simpleWebRTC room or video

Tags: javascript, php, video, webrtc

I'm using simpleWebRTC for a multi-party video chat.

Each user creates his own room.
When a user subscribes to another (in order to see this person 0 and registers in the db).

When a user chooses another - he gets this users username by XHR from the db.

I tried adding the data for the appropriate video (or room) - under the

```
webrtc.on('video added'......
```

Is there another way I can attach data to the video or room which is more reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just [added very recently](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/SimpleWebRTC/pull/261/files). You can now set `nick` on the config options passed to the constructor, which will be included in `onVideoAdded` -

```
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
     ... // your options here
     nick: 'my-user-id'
});

webrtc.on('videoAdded', function (peer) {
    //peer.nick is the other user's nick, and for them, this is yours
});
```

Comment: Thank you :-)
do you know of a service I can host signalMaster on?

Comment: or perhaps some step by step guide on doing that on node (for someone with no node knowledge)?
or - can i do that somehow with PHP?